# What is the encoding of Arabic text rendered like &#x62a;

Tags: facebook, character-encoding, rss

In my Facebook page the RSS feed's title of the page is rendered something like that:

```
&#x62a;&#x62c;&#x631;&#x628;&#x629; &#x646;&#x635; &#x639;&#x631;&#x628;&#x64a; &#x645;&#x646; &#x627;&#x644;&#x628;&#x62f;&#x627;&#x64a;&#x629; &#x628;&#x62f;&#x648;&#x646; &#x646;&#x635; &#x644;&#x627;&#x62a;&#x64a;&#x646;&#x64a;.
```

While the original text is:

```
تجربة نص عربي من البداية بدون نص لاتيني.
```

The RSS feed of the page could be found [here](https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=298887790292424).

What is the encode of this form? Why Facebook RSS render it like that?

Comment: If you are using php http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just the HTML/Unicode equivalent to the character. A list of available Unicode characters with the html encoding can be found here http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1472&number=128&names=-&unicodeinhtml=hex.

Facebook use this form to ensure a correct rendering on different devices in different countries.

Comment: So why Facebook use it only in title tag of the RSS not in description too?